# Matching the 3ds max camera view in my game 1:1

Tags: directx, camera, quaternion, 3dsmax, perspective

I want to match 1:1 the 3ds max camera render with my 3d engine (DirectX 11, C++).

I believe that my mesh exporter (coded with `MaxScript`) works fine, I see the right shapes.

But something about the perspective, translation (of the camera) and/or rotation is not quite right - the scene looks similar, but not the same:

[image]

[image]

As you can see:

- the window proportion and size is ok,
- the mesh looks fine (I'm not interested with the materials or shading now, just the 1:1 match of view & perspective),
- to get the better match, I had to translate the window (as you can see on the second image, **the corner of one has some offset**),
- **the rotation or rather perspective seems to be a bit wrong** (note the smaller teapot on second image).

I guess I've missed something:

- My object and camera are places in the **same position** as in 3ds max (3ds max is set to millimeters, engine don't use any units - e.g. camera is at `[20mm, 10mm, 0mm]` in 3ds max and `[20, 10, 0]` in game engine).
- Game engine camera uses `DirectX::XMMATRIX projection = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(DirectX::XM_PIDIV2, screenWidth / (FLOAT)screenHeight, 0.01f, 1000.0f);` and the 3ds max camera is set to **`FOV = 90`**:
  [image]
- The position and orientation of the object and camera (camera has no rotation applied) are converted **from 3ds max right-handed z-up coordinate system to engine's left-handed y-up coordinate system**. The orientation is expressed in quaternion and it's transformed from one system to another with:

.

```
temp = q.z
q.z = q.y
q.y = temp

q.z = -q.z
q.x = -q.x
q.y = -q.y
```

**What did I miss and should take into account when matching game engine view with 3d edition software like 3ds max?**